# How to stop Outlook downloading mail again after moving it to different PST file

Tags: email, download, microsoft-outlook-2010

My business partner and I download company email from the same POP server, with Outlook 2010 set up to leave mail on the server for a month, so that we can each get a copy of everything.

I've started archiving some of it to a separate PST file, which seems to have the effect of fooling Outlook into thinking that the email left on the server is new - so it downloads it all again.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can.

You guys should consider switching to Hosted Exchange with Microsoft itself. It is $5 per month, it is more stable than POP3 (PST's SUCK, OST's not so bad), synchronizes very quickly (after the first big one), you can access the same e-mail from multiple computers and it is always the same, your saved folders and contacts and calendars are also there, and lastly I have clients with 12GB mailboxes, who still have excellent performance, even though they access a server in Washington state from Massachusetts. You probably would not need to archive as you are doing now.

http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/en-us/pricing-exchange-online-email.aspx

Comment: +1 for hosted service.  Far less hassles.

Comment: Thanks.  Might well go for that in time.  For now, I'll just archive the stuff thats older than a month!